# Dollar Sign Character in Java

Tags: java, string, character

I am new to programming, but I am coming along.  I am using the online IDE written in php from www.compilejava.net.  My question is this.  I tried to use this code and I took it directly out of a Java textbook:

```
class DollarArguement {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        for(int i=0;i<args.length; i++) {
            if(args[i].startsWith("$")) {
                System.out.print(args[i]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It works for every character I have tried except "$".  I would like to put multiple strings in the commandline and search for $ values.  Does anyone know why this is not working?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please take some time to visit the [help], read [ask] and learn to use the formatting tools available in the StackOverflow editor.  i fixed it for you this time.

Comment: Please provide several sample command lines and the expected output.  You haven't told us what the code is intended to do.

Comment: The following strings were used in the command line : abcd 1234 $4.54 .    The output is blank.  Any of the characters I use in argument for the startsWith method will output the correct string.  Ex. "a" for strings abcd xyz 1234 will output: abcd.  Thanks.

Comment: Works fine for me (+1 for posting a complete example).  You do realize that it will print only the first argument that starts with `$`, right?  The `break` terminates the loop after the first match.

Comment: Thanks, Jim. I am using the online IDE from www.compilejava.com.  I think it is written in php, so maybe this explains the unexpected result that I am observing.  I will use another IDE and see if my problem is resolved.

Comment: This is my conclusion on the issue, with help from Jim in knowing that the code should work as expected.  The online IDE for Java written in php from www.complilejava.net will not allow the "$" character to be used with output in this specific context.  The reason is that in php the "$" character is reserved.  It thus can't be escaped without interfering with the code that enables the online IDE to function.  That is my conclusion.  Thanks, Jim.

Comment: I suggest you do three things: First, edit your original post to include the _crucial_ bit of information that you are running this on compilejava.com and not in an IDE. Second, download Eclipse or NetBeans to use as your IDE (they're both good, I prefer Eclipse but either will do). Third, post your comment above as a "self-answer" and then accept it after the required time delay, so others having this problem will be able to find an answered question.

Comment: try simply printing the args values to see what strings are making it into the program.  but i think the issue is this: on my mac (and I assume other variants of unix) if i type on the command line:  echo $hi it prints nothing. well, it's looking for a bash variable called hi which doesn't exist. so i dont think the values prefixed with $ are even making it into your application

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code on OSX and it displayed no results for "$", but if i changed it to "." it printed the first result (because of the break statement).

The reason is that on OSX (and other Unix systems) the bash terminal is looking for values which start with $ as these signify variable names.

you can test this simply by typing in a terminal

```
echo Hi

Hi

echo $Hi

(no result)
```

I assume the strings with the $ prefix are never evening making it into the program.

You can escape the $ with a backslash. Try running your program with these backslashes in your parameters.

```
echo \$Hi

$Hi
```

eg.

```
java -cp . DollarArguement \$test

$test
```

Comment: I agree with you in that I think the "$" character is restricted.  I believe that the problem I have is using an online IDE from www.compilejava.net.  It is written in PHP and the "$" character is restricted.  It is part of the PHP reserved characters, and in this specific application it is a restricted character that can't be processed and maintain the functionality of the online IDE.  This is what I belive to be the most reasonable conclusion.  Jim made suggestions in a previous post for more proficient IDEs to use.  Best.